# Pattern into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'd like to draw something like this pattern *(you can find below)* into an array of strings using 2 for loops.

```js
let matrix = [
  "....................",
  ".000000000000000000.",
  ".0................0.",
  ".0.00000000000000.0.",
  ".0.0............0.0.",
  ".0.0.0000000000.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0........0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0.000000.0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0.0....0.0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0.0.00.0.0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0.0.00.0.0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0.0....0.0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0.000000.0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0........0.0.0.",
  ".0.0.0000000000.0.0.",
  ".0.0............0.0.",
  ".0.00000000000000.0.",
  ".0................0.",
  ".000000000000000000.",
  "....................",
]

console.log(matrix)
```

**Note**: I'd like to be able to specify the modulo `%` ( the width of rows&cols of the same characters to get in one case a bigger in the other case a tinier pattern.

This is the code I got so far. Currently it is just be able to draw a "diagonal" from topLeft to bottomRight.

```js
let matrix = [
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
]

for (let y=0; y<matrix.length; y++) {
  for (let x=0; x<matrix[y].length; x++) {
    if (x==y) {
      let row = matrix[y].split("")
      row[x] = ".";
      matrix[y] = row.join("")
    }
  }
}

console.log(matrix)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Write down algorithm by pseudo code. Then we will talk.

Comment: I would have wrote down the whole Code&not have asked this question if I would know to write the algorithm down in pseudo code.  Think&write, not the other dierection :)

Comment: You got homework to do and you expect someone else to do it for you. Stack overflow does not like that. First try to write something yourself and if you come into a particular problem - ask about the solution to that specific problem. People will be more than willing to help in that case.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. What do you mean by specifying the modulo? Do you mean you want to be able to just specify the width and height of the pattern, or do you mean you want to be able to effect the periodicity of characters within the pattern? What happens if the width/height is odd/even? Does it have to be 2 for loops? Why?

Comment: @jonas00 `something like this` for me sounds like hard-coded value of string for each row. You do not provide any rules how pattern should be generated. What if you have matrix 1x1. It would be `.` or `0`?

Comment: @Justinas I think it does not matter. Just consider it frames that are placed inside each other. First frame is made of 0, then the frame inside is made of dots etc. You alter the frames until you reach the center.

Comment: I‘d like to use 2 for loops one for the X and one for Y. The matrix minimum size will be maybe 20x20 & and the matrix dimensions are 1:1.  About the modulo- it is the count how thick the lines of the dots are. In the examples above it is „1“. However the modulo operation is not the Main issue, I just got issues with the algorithm... :)

Comment: @jonas00: you have a task to do. I guess you encountered a problem and you ask for help. Please explain what your problem is and then people will gladly help.

Comment: Michael B - this is exactely hat I‘ve talked about- thanks:)

Comment: Thats really a pitty that it seems like nobody is able to fix my problem. Too bad:/

Comment: @jonas00  give it bounties so u can attract everybody. :-)

Comment: I did not thought that the question is that complicated. Crazy:)

Comment: I see how you think saying that will make people help you, @jonas00... but it is not going to work here :-)

Comment: Oh oh oh. Ok but ive already found a working solution on my own. P

Comment: So, it wasn't that difficult after all, was it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to solve this is to split the expected pattern into symmetric parts.

You can see that the First half of the array is reversed in the bottom half.

The same goes if you you split it vertically.

So only thing you need to implement is the following and reverse it a couple of times to get what you want.

```
..........
.000000000
.0........
.0.0000000
.0.0......
.0.0.00000
.0.0.0....
.0.0.0.000
.0.0.0.0..
.0.0.0.0.0
```

```js
let matrix = [
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000",
];
let base = matrix[0];
let baseArr = matrix[0].split('').slice(0, base.length/2);
let response = [];
for (let y=0; y<matrix.length/2; y++) {
  for (let x=y; x<baseArr.length; x++) {
    baseArr[x] = baseArr[x] == '0' ? '.' : '0';
  }
  response.push(baseArr.join('') + baseArr.slice(0, baseArr.length).reverse().join(''));
}
console.log(response);
let responseArray = response.concat(response.slice(0, response.length).reverse());
console.log(responseArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative approach for checking the outer frame and go to the inner smaller frames for checking by using an array for the starting points of the corners.

```js
var length = 20,
    even = Array.from({ length: length >> 2 }, (_, i) => i << 1),
    result = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => Array.from({ length }, (_, j) =>
        even.some(v =>
            i >= v && i <= length - 1 - v && (j === v || j === length - 1 - v) ||
            (i === v || i === length - 1 - v) && j >= v && j <= length - 1 - v)
            ? '.'
            : 'x'
    ).join(' '));

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result.join('\n');
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```